# Re-write links only not redirect

Tags: html

Hi I don't know much about htaccess and can't understand how the codes work.

Can someone help me do this

www.site.com/forums/index.php?/cp/3-welcome/

will only change the text itself to

www.site.com/forums/welcome

Not redirect it.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/forums/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/cp/6-monthly-member-profile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.org/forums/monthly-member-profile?  [R=302,L]

tried this but it's redirecting me thus giving me a 404 page

Answer (score 0):

You will first want to ensure rewrite rules are enabled.  You can do this through your .htaccess file using code similar to:

```
<Directory /var/www/website/html>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
    RewriteRule ... ...
    RewriteRule 
</Directory>
```

Once that is done then you should be able to run your RewriteCond command so that it will successfully redirect as the rewrite engine will be enabled.

Your redirect within the .htaccess file should look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^http://([^/]*)/forums/welcome(\d+)/(.*)$ 
http://$1/index.php?/cp/3-welcome/
```

Of course you may need to update/edit this as required for your specific needs, but this should at least give you a general idea.

Comment: mind if I ask how do I actually write the code?. 
www.site.com/forums/index.php?/cp/3-welcome/ to www.site.com/forums/welcome

Comment: cause i really don't know how to.

Comment: Is your site built manually, or through an application (such as WordPress/Joomla/Drupal) or something like that?

Comment: built with Invision. but the application is inside public_html/forums